# Best CI for Code Branching & Scaleable

Tags: java, continuous-integration, weblogic9.x

My group has asked me to look at various CIs. I have been looking at hudson and apache continuum. I would prefer something open source. We have over 100+ builds going right now and its just going to grow. It needs to do maven and ant builds this is a J2EE environment. We also do a code branch every month so it would need to be easy to branch code or make it so it can be stoped and configured to do the code branching. So any ideas? Or scripts to help hudson do this? Right now hudson looks like it will be a pain to do since every project has its own work space.

Answer (score 1):

> We have over 100+ builds going right now and its just going to grow.

Just because of this, I would pick Hudson (that will be able to scale using [distributed builds](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds) if necessary, or maybe even the cloud).

> We also do a code branch every month so it would need to be easy to branch code or make it so it can be stopped and configured to do the code branching.

I don't have such constraints but here are some interesting readings anyway:

- [Moving/copying/renaming jobs](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson#AdministeringHudson-Moving/copying/renamingjobs)
- [Ant target to clone a Template Hudson Job remotely](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Ant+Job+Clone+script)
- [HUDSON-682 - Clone workspace between jobs](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-682)

#### Related questions

- [Configure hudson to build multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839000/configure-hudson-to-build-multiple-branches)

#### See also

- [Ditching Continuum for Hudson](http://www.kenliu.net/2009/07/ditching-continuum-for-hudson.html)

Comment: Yea I knew about the distrubuted builds but I cant seem to just add a branch to the system and say hey build this. At least its not easily seen if it is there.